# how to install glassfish on an ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 14.04, glassfish

I am trying to install the glassfish on an ubuntu Machine 16.04
I follow the tutorial given here http://idroot.net/linux/install-glassfish-ubuntu-16-04/

however, everything goes well until 
I run this

```
glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain
```

and it gives an error

```
Waiting for domain1 to start ........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
serverNoStart
Command start-domain failed.
```

I found somewhere else https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0177/abgbk/index.html that I can use this

```
glassfish4/bin/asadmin start-domain domain1
```

unfortunately the same error

another attempt was to go to the

```
cd glassfish4/bin/
```

then

```
./asadmin
```

and again the same error

what is the problem? how can I diagnose this ?

Comment: I think you're running an old version.  try downloading the install file directly from oracle.