# what's the most flexible way to install glassfish?

Tags: server, apt, package-management, software-installation, glassfish

What's the best way to install [glassfish](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/)?  It's not possible through `umake`?  Looks like it's best to just download [manually](https://askubuntu.com/q/891768/45156).  (This is from 17.04 zesty.)

Preferably the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the only way to do it is via the `zip` file. That's what the [official documentation](https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/5.0/installation-guide.pdf#G5.1138954) says.